# Google Script to Start Timer in Clockify

Tags: google-apps-script, clockify

I'm trying to use a Google Script to start a timer in Clockify. The script does not give an error (such as 400 Bad Request), but no timer is ever started.

API Documentation at https://clockify.me/developers-api#operation--v1-workspaces--workspaceId--time-entries-post

```
function StartClockifyTimer() {
// Starts a timer based on the current sheet
// Step 1: Find PID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var FileNo = sheet.getSheetName();
  var PIDheaders = {"X-Api-Key" : "[apikey]", "content-type" : "application/json"};
  //var PIDpayload = JSON.stringify({'name' : FileNo});
  var PIDoptions = {
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  'method' : 'get',
  'headers' : PIDheaders,
  //'params' : PIDpayload
  };
  var PID = UrlFetchApp.getRequest('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[wid]/projects/', PIDoptions);
  for(i in PID) {
  Logger.log(i + ": " + PID[i]);
}
//Step 2: Use PID to start timer
  timezone = "GMT+" + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  var headers = {"X-Api-Key" : "[apikey]", "content-type" : "application/json"};
  var payload = JSON.stringify({'start' : date, 'projectId' : PID});
  var clockifyoptions = {
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  'method' : 'post',
  'headers' : headers,
  'payload' : payload
  };
  var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[wid]/time-entries/', clockifyoptions);
  Logger.log(r);
}
```

--EDIT-- Since posting, and thanks to the advice received, I've added in a new step in the process to find the PID by name. However, I cannot make the GET request work correctly. I need to query 'name' by FileNo as described in https://clockify.me/developers-api#operation--v1-workspaces--workspaceId--projects-get, but I can't get the GET request down pat. Even the above code with the commented out sections returns:

> [19-08-01 11:37:46:024 MDT] getAs: function getAs() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:025 MDT] getHeaders: function getHeaders() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:025 MDT] getContentText: function getContentText()
>   {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:026 MDT] getContent: function getContent() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:026 MDT] getResponseCode: function
>   getResponseCode() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:027 MDT] getAllHeaders: function getAllHeaders()
>   {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:027 MDT] toString: function toString() {/*
>   */}
>
> [19-08-01 11:37:46:028 MDT] getBlob: function getBlob() {/*
>   */}

I've since confirmed that using a hardcoded ProjectID in Step 2 works, so what I need help with is actually Step 1 - finding the PID. Can anyone help me format the GET request?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT. Leaving the code here for anyone else trying to hit Clockify's APIs.

```
function StartClockifyTimer() {
// Starts a timer based on the current sheet
// Step 1: Find PID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var FileNo = sheet.getSheetName();
  var url = 'https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[workspaceid]/projects?name='+FileNo
  const header = {
    "headers": {
      "X-Api-Key" : "[apikey]",
      "content-type" : "application/json",
      "Accept" : "*/*"
      }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, header)
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var PID = data[0]["id"];
  Logger.log(PID);

//Step 2: Use PID to start timer
  timezone = "GMT+" + new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  var headers = {"X-Api-Key" : "[apikey]", "content-type" : "application/json"};
  var payload = JSON.stringify({'start' : date, 'projectId' : PID});
  var clockifyoptions = {
  'muteHttpExceptions' : true,
  'method' : 'post',
  'headers' : headers,
  'payload' : payload
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[workspaceid]/time-entries/', clockifyoptions);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a couple of things to see what is going wrong:

(1) Replace

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[workspaceredacted]/time-entries/', clockifyoptions);
Logger.log(clockifyoptions);
```

with this

```
var r = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[workspaceredacted]/time-entries/', clockifyoptions);
Logger.log(r);
```

This way, the log will show you the response from the API and you can use that to debug.

(2) The `projectId` in the payload may be wrong.

Assuming the `projectID` is the name of the active sheet, try replacing

```
  var FileNo = ss.getSheetName();
```

with

```
  var FileNo = sheet.getSheetName();
```

Comment: You woke me up to an obvious issue - the projectID is not the sheet name but rather a number generated by Clockify when the project is created. I've written a new chunk of script and updated my question with the new script, but the error that I get is also posted. Any thoughts?